# get_gpu_info_c() does not detect GPUs

Tags: h2o4gpu

I'm new to stackverflow, sorry about the mistakes I may commit.

I was wondering if the h2o4gpu works with cuda 10.0 because I succesfully got it installed using conda but when I run 'get_gpu_info_c()' no GPUs are detected.

Thanks!

Comment: Try installing cuda 9.0 too.  You can install multiple cuda versions side-by-side.  h2o4gpu doesn’t have cuda 10.0 library support yet, but the drivers for cuda 10.0 do work.  so you can have the two versions of cuda installed side-by-side, and it’s fine.

Comment: Thanks! Could you tell me how I could go about installing CUDA 9.0 or CUDA 9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 without root or sudo access. I already have CUDA 10.0.